# How to make loop in scrapy class?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a site. But I have a problem. I made a class and a variable and gave it a link to scrape data from. But in website there are many categories in one page. Means there are countries names listed by alphabets `A, B upto Z`. I made a loop to just enter the first alphabet of a country starting from `A, B upto Z`, so that I could not repeat the links again and again. But it is not working. Its just giving me the names of the Countries which is in end of the variable `eleventh_category` list. If the list ends with C it will give me just the names of the countries starting from C not the B and A. I hope you understood..

```
class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dmoz'
    start_urls = ['http://dmoz-odp.org/']
    eleventh_category = ['A','B','C']
    for again in eleventh_category:
        save = f'http://dmoz-odp.org/Regional/{again}/'

    def parse(self, response):
        # collect data on page
        items = {
        'Navbar': response.css('#main-nav a::text').extract(),
        'Category_names': response.css('.top-cat a::text').extract(),
        'Subcategories': response.css('.sub-cat a::text').extract(),
        # this is eleventh_category
        'Eleventh_category': self.save
        }

    # save and call request to another page
    dct = [(self.save, self.alpha_country)]
    for page, callback in dct:
        yield response.follow(page, callback, meta={'items': items})

    def find_items(self, response, names, finder):
        items = response.meta['items']
        for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
            items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
            yield items

    def alpha_country(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        names = {'name1': 'Countries'}
        finder = {'finder1': '.browse-node::text'}
        for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
            items[name] = [i.strip() for i in response.css(find).extract() if i.strip()]
            yield items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the list ends with C it will give me just the names of the
>   countries starting from C

You are overriding the value in `save` at each iteration of your loop, so the final value will always be the last value of `eleventh_category`.

You can put the loop in the `parse` method:

```
class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dmoz'
    start_urls = ['http://dmoz-odp.org/']
    eleventh_category = ['A','B','C']

    def parse(self, response):    
        for again in self.eleventh_category:
            save = f'http://dmoz-odp.org/Regional/{again}/'
            items = {
                'Navbar': response.css('#main-nav a::text').extract(),
                'Category_names': response.css('.top-cat a::text').extract(),
                'Subcategories': response.css('.sub-cat a::text').extract(),
                # this is eleventh_category
                'Eleventh_category': save
            }
            # save and call request to another page
            dct = [(save, self.alpha_country)]
            for page, callback in dct:
                yield response.follow(page, callback, meta={'items': items})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am lost in your logics about variables outside functions (or you have problems with indents), but check this solution:

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dmoz'
    start_urls = ['http://dmoz-odp.org/']

    def parse(self, response):
        eleventh_category = ['A', 'B', 'C']
        for again in eleventh_category:
            save = 'http://dmoz-odp.org/Regional/{}/'.format(again)
            items = {
                'Navbar': response.css('#main-nav a::text').extract(),
                'Category_names': response.css('.top-cat a::text').extract(),
                'Subcategories': response.css('.sub-cat a::text').extract(),
                # this is eleventh_category
                'Eleventh_category': save,
            }
            yield response.follow(save, self.alpha_country, meta={'items': items})

    def find_items(self, response, names, finder):
        items = response.meta['items']
        for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
            items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
            yield items

    def alpha_country(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        names = {'name1': 'Countries'}
        finder = {'finder1': '.browse-node::text'}
        for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
            items[name] = [i.strip() for i in response.css(find).extract() if i.strip()]
            yield items
```

Here you have all logics and calls inside `parse` function, that is much easier and more readable.